# Python подсчитать количество значений в интервале

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть большой датафрейм вида :

```
id time(minutes)
1 23
2 25
3 123
4 245
5 9524
6 244
7 1
8 3
... .....
```

Как можно посчитать количество id в промежутках

- от 0 до 5 минут,
- от 5 минут до 10 минут,
- от 10 минут до 15 минут,
- от 15 до 20,
- от 20 до 25
- и от 25 до 30

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. покажите пример желаемого результата.

Comment: Пример :
от 0 до 5 минут - 23
от 5 до 10 - 2
от 10 до 15 - 244

Comment: ну вот объясните, как вы из данных в вопросе получили ваш желаемый результат? алгоритм какой?

Comment: Если без пандас, то это выглядит как накопление гистограммы. `for rec in recs   H[rec.time//5]+= 1`

Comment: Ну `pandas.cut` по идее, с указанием конкретных границ бинов https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то можно использовать `pandas.cut` и `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.random.randint(0, 59, size=1000)})
df['interval'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=[x*5 for x in range(13)], include_lowest=True)
df.groupby('interval').count()
```

Вывод:

```
                time
interval    
(-0.001, 5.0]   103
 (5.0, 10.0]    69
(10.0, 15.0]    90
(15.0, 20.0]    72
(20.0, 25.0]    80
(25.0, 30.0]    88
(30.0, 35.0]    88
(35.0, 40.0]    95
(40.0, 45.0]    91
(45.0, 50.0]    95
(50.0, 55.0]    76
(55.0, 60.0]    53
```

Хотя можно и проще - просто разделить время на 5 и группировать по этому значению.